# Retrieving static field in generic method by lambda expression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

Let's say i got this:

```
public class Foo{
    public string Bar;
}
```

Then i want to create a 'static reflection' to retrieve value of Bar like this:

```
public void Buzz<T>(T instance, Func<T, string> getProperty){
    var property = getProperty(instance);        
}
```

That should work. But what if Foo looks like this?

```
public class Foo{
    public static string Bar = "Fizz";
}
```

Can i retrieve value of Bar without passing instance of Foo?

Usage should look like:

```
var barValue = Buzz<Foo>(foo=>foo.Bar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd pass in a lambda which ignored its parameter, and use `default(T)` for the "instance" to use:

```
var barValue = Buzz<Foo>(x => Foo.Bar);
```

I suspect I'm missing your point somewhat though...

Comment: This is where idea came from - http://www.delphicsage.com/home/blog.aspx/d=131/title=Using_Net_3x_Lambda_Expressions_to_Write_More_Concise_Code

Comment: Sorry for being so vague - problem is that i'm feeling quite uncomfortable at this topic (trying to change that). But you hammered the nail... again...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Buzz<Foo>(x => Foo.Bar);
        }

        public static void Buzz<T>(Func<T, string> getPropertyValue)
        {
            var value = getPropertyValue(default(T));
            //value=="fizz" which is what i needed
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public static string Bar = "fizz";
    }
```

Thanks Jon.